# Difficulty reading SOAP response due to special chars

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have been dealing with SOAP Request/Responses, using C#. I am given how both the request and response format should be. I have successfully created a `[WebMethod]` that sends a request and I can retrieve the `XML` response from it. The problem is that the response I get looks like this

```
<soapenv:Header>
<v1:ResultStatus xmlns:v1="http://group.com/contract/vho/header/v1">
<bf:Timestamp xmlns:bf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2">27-Nov-17 1:42:24 PM</bf:Timestamp>
<bf:ErrorCode xmlns:bf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2">OK</bf:ErrorCode>
<bf:Description xmlns:bf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2">Integration Id cannot be retrieved for this user</bf:Description>
<v11:Message xmlns:v11="http://group.com/schema/common/v1">FAILURE</v11:Message>
</v1:ResultStatus>
</soapenv:Header>

<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<v1:CheckAuthenticationCredentialVBMResponse xmlns:v1="http://group.com/schema/vbm/identity/authentication-credential/v1">
<v1:AuthenticationCredentialVBO actionCode="ADD">
<v11:IDs xmlns:v11="http://group.com/schema/common/v1">
<v11:ID schemeName="Authentication Credential ID">5535</v11:ID>
</v11:IDs>
</v1:CheckAuthenticationCredentialVBMResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

And when I try to read it using `XmlDocument xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("bf:ErrorCode");` or `XmlDocument xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("v11:Message");` it considers `:` as special char and therefore cannot continue the execution, throwing this exception:

```
The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.
```

I have tried to find some kind of documentation about this, but I cannot seem to find something similar. Can someone help?

Please comment if further information is needed.

Comment: I fell in that trap too, SOAP is not xml, very similar but defently not follow its rules and therefore can't parse with xml parser, you need use SoapClient class

Comment: You probably want to add more of the response message to show that the namespaces "v1", "v11", and "bf" are defined.  It would also help to know the data type of "xmldoc" so that someone can assist in showing you the correct API to deal with the namespaces.

Comment: @Michael ok I will do a research on that. If you have any links of anything related with that, please share.

Comment: @Nathan i will edit the post with a very shorter version of the body and also declare xmldoc. thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: So what problem exactly you have with `xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("bf:ErrorCode")`? Throws exception? Returns not what you expect?

Comment: @Noel found it in google: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819935.aspx

Comment: @Evk I have updated my question. That is the exception i get when i try to read the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bf:ErrorCode` is xml element `ErrorCode` in namespace indicated by prefix `bf`. What namespace is represented by this prefix you can see in declaration:

```
xmlns:bf="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2"
```

So `bf:ErrorCode` is element `ErrorCode` in namespace `http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2`. Note that prefix name ("bf") is irrelevant, all that matters is namespace itself ("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2"). For that reason you should not search elements by namespace *prefix*, because it might change any time without changing meaning of xml document. You should only search by namespace.

With that knowledge you can get such elements like this:

```
string targetNamespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2";
var elements = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ErrorCode", targetNamespace);
```

Note that documentation of `GetElementsByTagName` suggests to not use this method and instead use `SelectNodes`. You can do the same with `SelectNodes` like this:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
// note that prefix doesn't _need_ to be "bf" 
// (though it could be "bf" if you wish)
nsManager.AddNamespace("anyPrefixHere", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2");
// use the same prefix here you used in `AddNamespace` call above
var elements = doc.SelectNodes("//anyPrefixHere:ErrorCode", nsManager);
```

Comment: great answer! totally worked. I will switch to SelectNodes.. seems easy to manage.